# Alt-Text for Images API

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there an API available to upload and image with alt text. I found a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http) but it seems to be applicable for thumbnails. Do we have something similar for a normal image publishing?